# How to prove that exists distinct $x_1,x_2 \in(a,b)$ such that $f '(x_1)f '(x_2)=1$?

Tags: analysis, contest-math

Assume $f:[a,b]\to[a,b]$ be continuous and differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $f(a)=a$, $f(b)=b$. How to prove that exists distinct $x_1,x_2 \in(a,b)$  such that $f '(x_1)f '(x_2)=1$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use the Mean Value Theorem you can get one point $x_1$, since $f(b)-f(a)=b-a$. Does it help?

Comment: @Sigur: What about the another distinct one?

Comment: @BabakSorouh, I don't know. So I asked if the first one could be useful.

Comment: See another excellent answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373408/how-to-prove-there-exist-distinct-a-i-such-fa-1fa-2fa-3-cdot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply the MVT for $g(x)=f(f(x)).$ Thus there exists $x_1 \in (a,b)$ s.t. $g'(x_1)=f'(x_1)f'(f(x_1))=1,$ so we're done.

**Added**:

If it happens $x_1=f(x_1),$ then apply the MVT for $g$ over $[a,x_1]$ therefore, there exists $x_2 \in (a,x_1)$ s.t. $g'(x_2)=f'(x_2)f'(f(x_2))=1.$ If $x_2 \neq f(x_2)$ so we're done, but if $x_2=f(x_2),$ since $(f'(x_1))^2=1=(f'(x_2))^2$ we will then have $f'(x_1)f'(x_2)=1$ or $-1.$ For the latter, we again need to apply the MTV over $[x_1,b]$ and run the argument for finding $x_3 \in (x_1,b),$ but now we can choose two points out of three ($x_1,x_2,x_3$) with the desired property.

Comment: Why does $x_1\neq f(x_1)$?

Comment: Ditto ${}{}{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: Not quite done. But, if $f(x_1)=x_1$, then one may apply the MVT on the intervals $[a,x_1]$ and $[x_1,b]$ to obtain the desired result.

Comment: If $f(x) \neq x$ for all $x \in [a, b]$, then there must be two fixed points $x_1 \neq x_2$ (perhaps just $a$ and $b$) such that no $x$ satisfying $x_1 \leq x \leq x_2$ is a fixed point for $f$.  Proceed with $x_1$ and $x_2$ in MVT.